# Can you alias an entity?

Tags: vhdl

Reading through the LRM, and it appears to imply anything can be aliased, but when I try the following, ActiveHDL tells me a design unit is expected:

```
entity some_entity is
.....
end entity;

alias another_name is some_entity;
```

The LRM states (in 6.6.1) that

*An object alias is an alias whose alias designator denotes an object (i.e., a constant, a variable, a signal, or a
file). A nonobject alias is an alias whose alias designator denotes some named entity other than an object.
An alias can be declared for all named entities except for labels, loop parameters, and generate parameters.*

Or is it just the case that because an alias is a declarative item, it must exist in an declarative region? But given that an alias takes on the same class as the aliased item, surely it should be allowed in the same region? This appears to compile ok:

```
package alias_package is
  alias another_name is work.some_entity;
end package;
```

Explanation for the above request: Lets say I want to rename `some_entity`, but it is used all over my design. Creating an alias to it would allow this, keeping the old name as an alias to the new one. Using the package would be unsuitable here as it would still require name modification at instantiation.

Is this worthy of a request for the next LRM?

Comment: LRM issues like this can be entered at:  https://gitlab.com/IEEE-P1076/VHDL-Issues     Like asked for in the answer below, use models would be appreciated.   One great use model is as BLM causes us to shift away from using names like AxiSlave and change it to something else (I am using AxiResponder), then old designs can continue to work.   Maybe rather than the conventional alias syntax, we would use something similar to package instances - even if we still use the name alias.

Comment: @JimLewis an idea, something like `entity some_entity alias alias_name is`

Comment: Mr 115 has a point about configuration declarations.   Interesting though that OSVVM verification components also provide the component declaration in a package.   If this were used, we would actually need an alias to a component declaration and not the entity.   OTOH if direct entity instantiation were used, then we need an alias to an entity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Or is it just the case that because an alias is a declarative item, it must exist in an declarative region?**

Yes. A design file is comprised of one or more design units and an entity declaration is a design unit. A design unit is comprised of one or more nested declarative regions. The root declarative region (with an optional context clause encompasses the design unit itself and any subordinate secondary design units.

There's no delimiter for declarative regions other than the end of a design unit.

> **But given that an alias takes on the same class as the aliased item, surely it should be allowed in the same region?**

No. A declaration doesn't take effect (it's name doesn't become visible) until after the declaration is complete. Here, after **end** [*entity*_simple_name] ;.

A new design unit begins with  optional context items (beginning with reserved words **library**, **use** or **context**) followed by a primary unit declaration or secondary unit body (indicated by one of the reserved words **entity**, **architecture**, **package**, **configuration**, **context** (here ignoring *PSL*, tool directives and comments).

Design units are independently analyzed.

The classes of aliases are object and non-object. An alias declaration targets the declaration of a named entity (and some name declarations are implicit).

> **Is this worthy of a request for the next LRM?**

This question is a request for a subjective opinion without a clear use case (providing examples, particularly in a design hierarchy). The reason isn't clear. What work are you trying to avoid?

As an opinion otherwise, no.

There are also parts of the standard that are poorly supported by synthesis vendors that already address modifying binding from the default by exception (configuration declarations containing context specifications or component instantiation with the reserved word **configuration**).

Comment: With the recent events in the US, some component developers (verification and perhaps also RTL) are dropping terminology "Slave" which is/was persistent in AXI models.   As a result, we break usage of the components for a significant number of people in the community.  A configuration would work if the user of the component were writing their own component declaration.    OTOH, if the verification component supplier also provided the component declaration in a package, we have a problem that cannot be solved by configuration declaration as the component name has changed.

Comment: There is likely an implied lack of backward compatibility for your contrived social justice use case. Port names implying master-slave relationships would also be affected  and an alias wouldn't help one bit. The answer notes the question author supplied no use cases.